# Tortoise SVN cannot connect to svnserve of newly created Subversion instance on SuSe Linux Server

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn

I just started a new position where none of the code is in version control. One of my duties is to fix that. I have some space on a SuSe 10 box, and subversion 1.6 is installed. Following the instructions in the O'Reilly Subversion book, I've got a subversion repository with code in it, and svnserve running:

`#lsof -i :3690

COMMAND    PID      USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME

svnserve 15115   xxxxxx    3u  IPv6 xxxxxxxx       TCP *:svn (LISTEN)`

Also, this command works
 `svnlook cat /home/svn/repos/ /project1/trunk/index.php`

However, when I try to connect to the subversion repository from my desktop (running Windows) using TortoiseSVN, I get the error

Can't connect to host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I have tried multiple repository URLs, including:

- svn://internalmachinename.internalnetwork.com/project1
- svn://machinename/project1
- svn://machinename/repos/project1
- svn://machinename/svn/repos/project1
- svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/project1/trunk:3690

I don't have access to Cygwin because of the company's firewall policy, so I can't try to connect via the command line.

Comment: The SuSE box has most likely its firewall turned on..

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to use svn, use the simple ping command to check the connection between the two computers.
Only if that works, go to the next step (which still isn't using svn!): check if you can reach the correct port using telnet.

Then, and only then should you try to use svn to do the connection.

Comment: I didn't include that I had tried pinging the server and also was connected to it remotely through Putty.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall suggestion was close - it was the firewall on my Windows desktop that was keeping Subversion from connecting.